# How to change value of second dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, model-view-controller

Im not able to set value of the second dropdown on pressing the edit button. the first one changes with ease. but the second one doesnt seem to change even though i am using the same way to change the value of the first dropdown but for some reason the second one doesnt changee

HTML:

```
<div style=" width: 550px; padding: 40px; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%; border: 1px solid black " class="container center-div">

        <form>


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PersonName">Person Id</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonId" name="PersonId" placeholder="Id" disabled>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PersonName">Person Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonName" name="PersonName" placeholder="Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="PersonName">Person Age</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="PersonAge" name="PersonAge" placeholder="Age">
            </div>


            <input type="button" value="Save" id="snddet" name="snddet" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 45px; margin-left: 190px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px;" class="btn btn-primary">

            <label for="PersonCountry">Country:</label>
            <select style="margin-top:10px" class="mdb-select md-form" id="PersonCountry" name="PersonCountry" >
                <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Country</option>
                @foreach (var item in (List<String>)ViewBag.list)
                {
                    <option value='@item'>@item</option>
                }
            </select>

            <label for="PersonCity">City:</label>
            <select class="mdb-select md-form" id="PersonCity" name="PersonCity" >
                <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a City</option>


            </select>


</form>

        <button id="upd" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 50px" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>Save Changes</button>  


        <table id="mytable" class="table table-reflow" border='1' style="margin-top:50px; text-align:center "></table>
</div>
```

Script:

```
    function loadctr()
    {
        $('#PersonCountry').change(function () {
            var a = document.getElementById("PersonCountry").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/Person/getCountry",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { PersonCountry: a },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function (data) {
                    var len = data.length;
                    var s = '<option value="-1"disabled selected>Please Select a City</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        s += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>';
                    }
                    $("#PersonCity").html(s);                       
                },

                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert(errMsg);
                }
            });

        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadrec();
        loadctr();


    });



    function loadrec() {

        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "/Person/getTable",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                success: function (data) {
                    debugger
                    var i = 1;
                    var j = 1;
                    $('#mytable').append('<tr><th style="text-align:center" >  Id</th><th style="text-align:center">  Name</th><th style="text-align:center">  Age</th><th style="text-align:center">  Country</th><th style="text-align:center">  City</th><th style="text-align:center">  Options</th></tr>');
                    $(data).each(
                               function () {                                      
                                   $('#mytable').append('<tr><td>' + this.Id + '</td><td id="name-' + this.name + '">' + this.name + '</td><td id="age-' + this.age + '">' + this.age + '</td><td>' + this.country + '</td><td>' + this.city + '</td><td> <button class="delbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Delete </button> <button class="editbtn" id= "' + this.Id + '"> Edit </button> </td></tr>')
                                   if (i == data.length) {
                                       $(".delbtn").click(function () {
                                           var del = $(this).attr('id');
                                           $.ajax({
                                               type: "get",
                                               url: "/Person/delRow",
                                               dataType: "json",
                                               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                               data: { del: del },
                                               success: function (data) {
                                                   alert(data);
                                                   $("#mytable").empty();
                                                   loadrec();
                                                   $('#PersonId').val("");
                                                   $('#PersonName').val("");
                                                   $('#PersonAge').val("");
                                                   $('#PersonCountry').val("");
                                                   $('#PersonCity').val("");



                                               },
                                               failure: function (errMsg) {
                                                   alert("failure")
                                               }
                                           })
                                       });
                                       $(".editbtn").click(function () {
                                           var edit = $(this).attr('id');
                                           $('#PersonId').val($(this).parent().siblings()[0].innerText);
                                           $('#PersonName').val($(this).parent().siblings()[1].innerText);
                                           $('#PersonAge').val($(this).parent().siblings()[2].innerText);                                               
                                           $('#PersonCountry').val($(this).parent().siblings()[3].innerText);
                                           $('#PersonCountry').change();
                                           $('#PersonCity').val($(this).parent().siblings()[4].innerText);
                                           jQuery("#upd").prop('disabled', false);
                                           jQuery("#snddet").prop('disabled', true);


                                       });
                                   }
                                   i = i + 1;
                               })
                }
            })
        });


    }


    $('#snddet').click(function () {
        var name = document.getElementById("PersonName").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("PersonAge").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("PersonCountry").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("PersonCity").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/Person/SendDetails",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { name: name, age: age, country: country, city: city },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#mytable").empty();
                loadrec();
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
        $('#PersonId').val("");
        $('#PersonName').val("");
        $('#PersonAge').val("");
        $('#PersonCountry').val("");
        $('#PersonCity').val("");
    });

    $('#upd').click(function () {
        var Id = document.getElementById("PersonId").value;
        var name = document.getElementById("PersonName").value;
        var age = document.getElementById("PersonAge").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("PersonCountry").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("PersonCity").value;

        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/Person/editData",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { Id: Id, name: name, age: age, country: country, city: city },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
                $("#mytable").empty();
                loadrec();
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
        jQuery("#upd").prop('disabled', true);
        $('#PersonId').val("");
        $('#PersonName').val("");
        $('#PersonAge').val("");
        $('#PersonCountry').val("");
        $('#PersonCity').val("");
        jQuery("#snddet").prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

Comment: a fiddle with some sort of example will help a lot

Comment: Could you improve the formatting and reduce your code to the essentials, please?

Comment: i have reduced the code

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```js
    
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#PersonCountry').trigger('change');//instead of giving change function inside another function,use this to trigger change event
});

 
 //city dropdown loading
 $('#PersonCountry').change(function () {
    var a = document.getElementById("PersonCountry").value;
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/Person/getCountry",
           dataType: "json",
           data: { PersonCountry: a },
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           success: function (data) {
             $('#PersonCity').empty();
             if (data.length !== 0) {
                var s = '<option value="-1"disabled selected>Please Select a City</option>';
                $.each(data, function (k, item) {
                   s += '<option value="' + data[i] + '">' + data[i] + '</option>'; 
                });
                $("#PersonCity").append(s);   
             }     
          },
          failure: function (errMsg) {
             alert(errMsg);
           }
         });

        });
```

```html
 <label for="PersonCountry">Country:</label>
            <select style="margin-top:10px" class="mdb-select md-form" id="PersonCountry" name="PersonCountry" >
                <option value="" disabled selected>Please Select a Country</option>
                @foreach (var item in (List<String>)ViewBag.list)
                {
                    <option value='@item'>@item</option>
                }
            </select>

            <label for="PersonCity">City:</label>
            <select class="mdb-select md-form" id="PersonCity" name="PersonCity" >
              
            </select>
```

Comment: it works when the page is loaded. what i wanted to say was when i press the edit button from within the table i want to get all the values. i get everything except for the person city. the dropdown will populate but will not pass the value from the edit button function

Comment: @SalehAdnan on country change you want to load cities right?

Comment: i need to change the value of the city by this function $"editbtn". it passes the values to the text boxes and the dropdown. now the problem is that it selects the right option from the country dropdown but doesnt select the option from the city dropdown

Comment: which is your edit button click function in the above? @SalehAdnan

Comment: inside `$(".editbtn").click(function () { $('#PersonCountry').trigger('change'); }` trigger country change after assigning values to textboxes @SalehAdnan

Comment: if you are getting correct value in your `$(".editbtn").click(function () {}`  try replacing `$('#PersonCity').val($(this).parent().siblings()[4].innerText);`  to  $(`#PersonCity option[value='+$(this).parent().siblings()[4].innerText+']`).prop('selected', true);